# All Textarea's in AS3 update,when I edit one. Why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have textArea's on the stage in CS5 and when I go to change the color in one, they all change. Why is that? They all have separate instance names. Is there a way to edit just one textarea without having the rest of them update? Do I have to do this in code?

Comment: Do you select the textarea on stage to change its properties, or do you change something in the library? The former should alter only one textarea, the latter should alter all of them.

Comment: Only one on the stage. That's the most bizarre part. I got them all fro the library (obviously) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you create a MovieClip and put a text area there, so when you edit this text area all the text in the stage will be edited, even if they been given different instance name. This is because you edit the default for that MovieClip.

But if you will edit from code, you will edit by instance name, and then it will be fine, because you override the default.